# Generate n choose 2 combinations in python on very large data sets

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create n choose 2 combinations and am currently using pythons itertools.combinations module.

For a single list of 30,000 strings, creating the combinations runs for hours and uses many gigs of ram, ie

```
list(itertools.combinations(longlist,2))
```

is there a method of generating combinations that is potentially better optimized for large objects in memory? Alternately is there a way of using numpy to speed up the process?

Comment: it would not use many gigs of ram if you iterated over instead of loading it all into a list... what are you actually trying to do? do you actually need to generate all the combinations? or you just need to pick some random ones? or you just need to know how many there are?

Comment: What do you need to do with the combinations?  If you remove the `list` call, it will take little memory, but you'll just get one combination at a time instead of all at once.  In any case, there are ~450 million combinations, so anything you do with them is likely to take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Have you seen https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.special.binom.html ?

Comment: The computation is going be done in spark and the combinations will be stored in a Hive table. A string distance function will be applied to the pairs for feature engineering. I know that its a generator and I could calculate the distance by iterating through the generator. But for the initial case, I need to be able to fully evaluate the entire data structure and save it to disk

Comment: how are you going to save it to disk? why don't you just iterate over, say, 2 million elements at a time and write each chunk to disk?

Comment: It is splitting hairs -- there is over 100 gigs of ram so reading it into memory vs chunking to disk is not the issue, I was hoping to find a potentially faster combinations algorithm than whats in itertools. In the real use case the data will be written to HDFS

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a generator based on [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)
These are the indices of the upper trianle of an nxn square matrix, where n = `len(long_list)`

The problem is that the entire set of indices are created first.  itertools does not do this and only generates each combination one at a time.

```
def combinations_of_2(l):
    for i, j in zip(*np.triu_indices(len(l), 1)):
        yield l[i], l[j]

long_list = list('abc')
c = combinations_of_2(long_list)
list(c)

[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

---

To get them all at once

```
a = np.array(long_list)
i, j = np.triu_indices(len(a), 1)
np.stack([a[i], a[j]]).T

array([['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'c'],
       ['b', 'c']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

---

***timing***
`long_list = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), (3, 1000))).sum().tolist()`
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can instantly know how many combinations there are by using binomial coeficient there are (30k choose 2) way to solve this = `math.factorial(30000)//(math.factorial(2)*math.factorial(30000-2))` = `449985000` combinations

that said itertools returns a generator so you can iterate over it without loading all the combinations in memory into one big list